# how to await two tasks in a coroutine?

Tags: python-asyncio

i am study asyncio on python3.7.5  and i had choosed implement a telentd as the task

now after some coding, i found its almost done, except one weird things , code below

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import asyncio
import os
import pty
import sys
import termios
from subprocess import Popen


async def copyto(src, dst):
    while True:
        if getattr(src, 'read', None):
            # print(f"src has read")
            buf = await src.read(1024)
        else:
            # print(f"src dont have read")
            buf = os.read(src, 1024)

        if getattr(dst, 'write', None):
            # print(f"dst has write")
            dst.write(buf)
            await dst.drain()
        else:
            # print(f"dst dont has write")
            os.write(dst, buf)


async def handlerCommand(reader, writer):
    # command = 'podman run -it --rm alpine bash'
    command = 'bash'

    oldTty = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin)

    # open pseudo-terminal to interact with subprocess
    masterFd, slaveFd = pty.openpty()

    # force remote side into character mode
    writer.write(b"\xff\xfd\x22\xff\xfb\x01")

    # use os.setsid() make it run in a new process group, or bash job control will not be enabled
    Popen(
        command,
        preexec_fn=os.setsid,
        stdin=slaveFd,
        stdout=slaveFd,
        stderr=slaveFd,
        universal_newlines=True)

    os.write(masterFd, b"ls\n")
    await asyncio.gather(
        copyto(masterFd, writer),
        copyto(reader, masterFd)
    )

    # restore tty settings back
    termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin, termios.TCSADRAIN, oldTty)


async def main(host, port):
    server = await asyncio.start_server(
        handlerCommand,
        host,
        port
    )

    addr = server.sockets[0].getsockname()
    print(f'Serving on {addr}')

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main('127.0.0.1', 8888))
```

this is a full runable code, and as you can see, when user connected, i will start a bash process and connect it to user's socket. but now my problem is user could saw output from the process, while cant send any keystroke to the process.

i thought it might be that my understanding of asyncio's gather. but i am not sure

on the client side i just use

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 8888
```

a factored version of the server below, those term stuff still not solved
but on asyncio level, i think the problem solved despite the solution is too heavy

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
a telnet server sample
"""

import asyncio
import os
import pty
import tty
from subprocess import Popen

import concurrent.futures

import telnetlib3


async def sock2f(sock, fobj):
    """
    copy from socket to fobj
    """
    while True:
        buf = await sock.read(1)

        if not buf:
            print(f"sock2f break")
            break

        print(f"sock2fd {buf}")

        fobj.write(buf)
        fobj.flush()


async def f2sock(fobj, sock):
    """
    copy from fobj to sock
    """
    print(f"f2sock 开始")

    def _block_read(length):
        return fobj.read(length)

    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
        while True:
            print(f"f2sock readbuf")
            buf = await loop.run_in_executor(pool, _block_read, 32)
            print(f"f2sock readbuf done")

            if not buf:
                print(f"f2sock break")
                break

            print(f"f2sock {buf}")

            sock.write(buf)
            await sock.drain()


async def handlerCommand(reader, writer):
    """
    ha
    """
    # command = 'podman run -it --rm alpine bash'
    command = 'bash'

    # open pseudo-terminal to interact with subprocess
    masterFd, slaveFd = pty.openpty()
    tty.setraw(slaveFd)
    tty.setraw(masterFd)

    Popen(
        command,
        bufsize=0,
        preexec_fn=os.setsid,
        stdin=slaveFd,
        stdout=slaveFd,
        stderr=slaveFd,
        universal_newlines=True,
        # close_fds=True,
        shell=True
    )

    os.write(masterFd, b"ls\n")

    m_read = os.fdopen(masterFd, 'rb')
    m_write = os.fdopen(masterFd, 'wb')
    await asyncio.gather(
        f2sock(m_read, writer),
        sock2f(reader, m_write),
    )


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = telnetlib3.create_server(
    port=6023,
    term="xterm-256color",
    encoding=False,
    shell=handlerCommand
)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
```

Comment: As implemented, `copyto` will block the event loop when `src` and `dst` don't have `read` and `write` respectively. Generally you cannot use asyncio to talk to raw file descriptors like that, unless you really know what you're doing (e.g. carefully open them in non-blocking mode and handle `EAGAIN`).

Comment: @user4815162342  thanks for the helpful information, so were there any wrap in asyncio for awaitable fd reading/writing?

Comment: *were there any wrap in asyncio for awaitable fd reading/writing* - Yes, but in the form of [low-level API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#watching-file-descriptors), but you'll need to ensure that your file descriptors are non-blocking when you actually read them. Before writing such low-level code, I recommend watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCs5OvhV9S4) to understand, in principle, how asyncio-like libraries actually work.

Comment: @user4815162342 thanks, i think i had the solution, i need to write that wrapper my self, which set the fd as non-blocking and make a future inside it by using those low level apis. its really strange why the official library dont gave a wrapper to do this, since its a common needs i guess

Comment: Glad to hear! Please do write an answer if you get it working, it might be useful to others (and you'll get a review of sorts). *its really strange why the official library dont gave a wrapper to do this* - If you're referring to generic support for IO on raw file descriptors, I think the reason is that it would be non-portable, as Windows doesn't have true kernel level file descriptors (its handles might be considered the closest equivalent). Asyncio concentrates on robust and portable support for sockets, which is what most people need and what other libraries build on.

Comment: @user4815162342  i think i had use ThreadPool to make it work, but the term stuff still not solved, also the thread solution is too heavy i think. i will append the code to the question